# Im trying to make a chatbot that ask you questions at random but I keep getting "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

Tags: python, random, chatbot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1zRC.png

Im trying to make a chatbot that ask you questions at random but I keep getting "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list" and I don't know what to do.

```
import random

username = ""
username = input("What would you like me to call you?")


questions = [
'What is your favorite color?',
'What is your favorite animal?', 
'What are your thoughts on call of duty?',
'Do you like minecraft?' ,
'What do you do to get rid of stress?',
'What three words best describe you?',
'What’s your favorite number? Why?',
'What do you think of tattoos? Do you have any?',
'Do you have any pets? What are their names?'
    ]





 def generate_response(user_input):
  responses = [
"How interesting "+ username + "!",
"You don't say "+ username +"!",
"Very cool "+ username +"!",
 "ok "+ username
      ]
 return random.choice(responses)



 def init_chat():
 quit_character = 'q'

 user_input = input("Hello, how are you " + username + "?\n")
 print(random_question + username)

 while user_input != quit_character:
 user_input = input(generate_response(user_input) + "\n")
 random_question = random.choices(questions)
 generate_response()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
  init_chat()
```

Comment: `random_question = random.choices(questions)` is a list. Use `random_question = random.choice(questions)` if you just want one element from `questions`.

Comment: `generate_response()` Aren't you supposed to pass a parameter to this function?

Answer (score 1):

You received a `TypeError` on line 41 of your code because you are attempting to concatenate a list (`random_question`) with a string (`username`).

In line 22, you write

```
random_question = random.choices(questions)
```

`random.choices()` returns a list. Use

```
random_question = random.choice(questions)
```

if you just want one element from questions.

Comment: @Scrub Overlord If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer. There is absolutely no obligation to do this.